# Get Resharper to Consume StyleCop configuration

Tags: resharper, stylecop

Our project already has a StyleCop configuration. I am using ReSharper and I would like to be able to have R# use the StyleCop settings.

I know that you can use StyleCopForResharper to build the settings in Resharper and export them as a StyleCop configuration, but can you do the reverse and have Resharper consume the existing StyleCop config?

Comment: I would love to know if this is possible too. I use Resharper and StyleCop together, and find it terribly annoying that many of R#'s naming convention and refactors directly go against StyleCop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure is this post still actual. There is free [StyleCop for ReSharper](http://www.codeplex.com/StyleCopForReSharper) at CodePlex.

It uses  StyleCop assembly so it will use project file settings.

Comment: It appears it is a new drop that does say it reads current StyleCop settings. It was just dropped yesterday, apparently. Thanks klashar, I'll try it out some time today!

Comment: This is fantastic feature - you can fix the StyleCop warning while editing your code and on code cleanup!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any way to do this, but it is possible for R# to layout your members/properties/methods etc. to comply with StyleCop.  Check out my blog post at http://stevedunns.blogspot.com/2009/03/halt-this-is-stylecop-you-are-in.html.

HTH.

Steve

Comment: At any rate, it looks like there's no automatic way to do this. I'll either be managing settings one-by-one, or something just like it. Thanks for the link, Steve. Good stuff.