# Is there a way to sync settings from Settings.StyleCop to ReSharper?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper, stylecop

My question is quite simple: Is there a way to sync the changes you make in the Settings.StyleCop file into the ReSharper settings?

As it is now I have to first make the changes in Settings.StyleCop (so that StyleCop can validate my code using the rules I want) and then I have to make the same changes in ReSharper to get syntax highlighting and warnings in code as i type.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041373/get-resharper-to-consume-stylecop-configuration) but it doesn't seem to apply anymore. ReSharper doesn't read StyleCop.Settings.

Answer (score 3):

With the StyleCop (4.7.44.0) plugin for R#:

Under the R# options, Tools, StyleCop section:

[image]

Comment: Also, if you have installed StyleCop before Resharper you may not see the StyleCop plugin in Resharper, as I just did now. In this case simple re-run the StyleCop installer, hit change and then you should see a R# integration - enable that and you should be sorted.

Comment: For R# 9 I had to 
1) include prerelease packages in Resharper Options -> Environment -> Extension Manager, and then install the prerelease extension for StyleCop
2) Press the Reset C# Code Style Options as shown here, and then
3) Reload the project before my custom StyleCop rules were recognized.